# Django NoReverseMatch at

Tags: django

I have the following URLs:

`url(r'^%sdform/' %(URLPREFIX), pv.dform, name='dform'),`

`url(r'^%sform/(P?<growl>.*)/' %(URLPREFIX), pv.dform, name='dform'),`

The view code:

`def dform(request, growl = None)` is the method signature

The redirect code:

```
msg = 'test'
return redirect('dform', growl=msg)
```

Any idea why I get that error?  I'm sending the right parameter to the right view method with the right argument name and all that.

***EDIT:***
Based on the answer below, I tried:

`url(r'^%sdform/(P?<growl>.*)/' %(URLPREFIX), pv.dform, name='dform_message')`

And changed the redirect to:

`return redirect('dform_message', growl='Updated Settings')`

I still get `NoReverseMatch`

Comment: What is URLPREFIX? That really doesn't seem to be the right way of constructing your URL patterns.

Comment: Why not?  I'm setting up a reverse proxy via lighttpd, so the app may be at `http://mydomain/djangoapp1` and also at `http://mydomian2/djangoapp2` and so on, so I can just set an environment variable and read it via settings.py to set the "application context" for the webapp.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: Your web server should be passing on the location via the SCRIPT_NAME environment variable; Django automatically reads that and takes care of everything. You don't need to do what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did not see that in the documentation.  That was not my experience, is there a setting for that.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you shall not use the same names for different urls ([django docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)).

Comment: I changed the name and get the same result.

Comment: Names don't have to be unique. In fact, when you have multiple patterns with different parameters for the same view, I would recommend to give them the same name.